# Tangent Lines of Vector Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I apologize if this question is too trivial, but I don't have anyone else to ask and I don't understand it.

In class, we solved an example. The question was "Find the parametric equation of the line tangent to the curve $\vec{r}(t)=t\overrightarrow{i}+e^{-t}\overrightarrow{j}+(2t-t^2)\overrightarrow{k}$ at the point $(0,1,0)$."

We differentiated $\vec{r}(t)$ and plugged in $0$ to get a direction vector. Using the direction vector and the base point, we found the parametric equation of the line.

However, how can a function with 3 dimensions have a tangent "line"? Shouldn't it be a plane? Couldn't any tangent line be rotated with respect to the base point to create a plane? I am imagining a shape like a windmill.

What we did to solve the question sounds reasonable, but I don't think I really understand it. It seems like there must be something that makes the line we found more "special" than all the other lines in the plane that I (tried to) describe.

Comment: No, if you're an ant walking along the curve, you have only one degree of freedom in how you can walk — either forward along the curve or backward — and that direction, instantaneously, is (plus or minus) the direction of the velocity vector. This determines a line. You have no alternative direction of motion.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes so much sense! Thank you so much!